# Handling empty list in for loop python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, list

I have come across a situation where I am dealing a nest list with nested dictionaries.
Sometimes, one of the dictionary key would have an empty list. So, when iterating with for loop, I am getting and list index out of range error.

Below, I will give you a small portion of the data from dataframe:

```
list = [{'author_position': 'first',
  'author': {'id': 'https://openalex.org/A5012408034',
   'display_name': 'Vincent S. Tagliabracci',
   'orcid': 'https://orcid.org/0000-0002-9735-4678'},
  'institutions': [],
  'is_corresponding': False,
  'raw_affiliation_string': 'Molecular Biology',
  'raw_affiliation_strings': ['Molecular Biology']},
 {'author_position': 'last',
  'author': {'id': 'https://openalex.org/A5076217348',
   'display_name': 'Peter J. Roach',
   'orcid': None},
  'institutions': [{'id': 'https://openalex.org/I55769427',
    'display_name': 'Indiana University – Purdue University Indianapolis',
    'ror': 'https://ror.org/05gxnyn08',
    'country_code': 'US',
    'type': 'education'}],
  'is_corresponding': False,
  'raw_affiliation_string': 'Indiana-University Purdue-University Indianapolis',
  'raw_affiliation_strings': ['Indiana-University Purdue-University Indianapolis']}]
```

This list has two nested dictionaries. I am trying to extract a list of informations:

[author_id, author_name, institution_id, institution_name, etc... ] in a list or tuple

If you notice, the first item 'institutions' is an empty list whereas the second is not empty and that is giving me hard time.
Below is my code snippet:

```
author_id = []
institution_id = []
for item in list:
    author_id.append(item['author']['id'])
    if item['institutions'][0]:
        institution_id.append(item['institutions'][0]['id'])
institution_id
```

The error I am getting is:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
/home/azureuser/******.ipynb Cell 20 line 5
      3 for item in a[1]:
      4     author_id.append(item['author']['id'])
----> 5     if item['institutions'][0]:
      6         institution_id.append(item['institutions'][0]['id'])
      7 institution_id 

IndexError: list index out of range
```

I would really appreciate if someone can help me navigate this situation.
Thank you all!

Comment: Check if the list is empty with an `if`? `try-except` an `IndexError` (or, potentially, `LookupError`)?

Comment: use `if item['institutions']:`

Comment: Answers and comments are great but I'd reiterate: "Don't use `list` as a variable name." `list` is a built-in and using it as a variable could cause other issues if you happen to use the `list` function or type.

Comment: Rest assure that I am not using list as var in my actual code. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please do not use `list` as a variable name.

**You can simply do `if item['institutions']` it will only proceed if the list is non-empty**

```
lst = [{'author_position': 'first',
  'author': {'id': 'https://openalex.org/A5012408034',
   'display_name': 'Vincent S. Tagliabracci',
   'orcid': 'https://orcid.org/0000-0002-9735-4678'},
  'institutions': [],
  'is_corresponding': False,
  'raw_affiliation_string': 'Molecular Biology',
  'raw_affiliation_strings': ['Molecular Biology']},
 {'author_position': 'last',
  'author': {'id': 'https://openalex.org/A5076217348',
   'display_name': 'Peter J. Roach',
   'orcid': None},
  'institutions': [{'id': 'https://openalex.org/I55769427',
    'display_name': 'Indiana University – Purdue University Indianapolis',
    'ror': 'https://ror.org/05gxnyn08',
    'country_code': 'US',
    'type': 'education'}],
  'is_corresponding': False,
  'raw_affiliation_string': 'Indiana-University Purdue-University Indianapolis',
  'raw_affiliation_strings': ['Indiana-University Purdue-University Indianapolis']}]
```

---

```
author_id = []
institution_id = []
for item in lst:
    author_id.append(item['author']['id'])
    if item['institutions']:
        institution_id.append(item['institutions'][0]['id'])
```

Comment: I thought I did this, but I found an error on my code. Thanks

Comment: @stackword_0 you're welcome

Answer (score 0):

In the list is empty you cannot access any index, since `list[0]` means that you access the first item in the list.
Instead, you should first check if the list contains any items like:

```
if len(list) > 0:
```

Comment: Or, more concisely: `if mylist:` … don’t use `list` as a variable name.

Comment: I am not using list as variable in my actual codes. I only put here as example!

Comment: Great, then neither here please :)

Answer (score 0):

On line five, you try to access the 0 index even though it doesn’t exists.

Instead of `if item['institutions'][0]:`, try `if len(item['institutions']) > 0:`.

```
for item in list:
    author_id.append(item['author']['id'])
    if len(item['institutions']) > 0:
        institution_id.append(item['institutions'][0]['id'])
institution_id
```

Comment: Note that `if len(item['institutions']) > 0` is more concise with `if item['institutions']`